# How to do color line who match a condtion in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I try do color lines who correspond to a conditon,
Here my database :

[image: database]

I would like to color line when libelle=XV28

I did it :

```
Option Compare Text

Sub Bouton3_Cliquer()

    Dim Derniere_ligne As Long
    Dim ligne_en_cours As Long
    Dim libelle As String

    Derniere_ligne = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For ligne_en_cours = 2 To Derniere_ligne

    libelle = Cells(ligne_en_cours, 5).Value


    If libelle = "XV28" Then
        libelle = Cells(ligne_en_cours, 5).Value
        Cells(ligne_en_cours).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

But it doesn't work , I have only first line in color but it is name's column

Thanks for reading me

PS:
I would like to know how I can have number of column without say myself.

For example, in this code :

```
Sub reset()

    Dim Derniere_ligne As Long
    Dim ligne_en_cours As Long
    Dim libelle As String

    Derniere_ligne = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For ligne_en_cours = 2 To Derniere_ligne

    libelle = Cells(ligne_en_cours, 4).Value


    If libelle = "XZ" Then
     Rows(ligne_en_cours).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 'this will change colour for whole row
End If


    Next


End Sub
```

I say

```
libelle = Cells(ligne_en_cours, 4).Value
```

But I would like to replace the 4 per the index of libelle who would return me 4 becuase sometimes, I can have 1 column more and then all would be false.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this

```
If libelle = "XZ" Then
     rows(ligne_en_cours).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'this will change colour for whole row               
End If
```

If you want one cell you need to provide row and column number
`cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber)`

 Or you can use range like this 
`Range("A" & ligne_en_cours & ":D" & ligne_en_cours).Interior.ColorIndex = 4`

Comment: perfect it works,   but you know how I can reset all ?  I mean that now I have all line in color when libelle ="XZ"    but how to create a macro to delete the color

Comment: this should work 'rows(ligne_en_cours).interior.colorindex = xlnone'

Answer (score 0):

Few things I can see that would be an issue:

- `If libelle = "XV28" Then` needs to read `XZ`
- `Cells(rowNum,colNum)` has a row & column component (you only have a row in your `If` statement)... maybe you want `Rows()` rather than `Cells()`
- Verify that you're working in `Columns(5)`/`Range("E:E")`

If those criteria are all met, you should be rocking and rolling.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know how I can have number of column without say myself.

For example, in this code :

```
Sub reset()

    Dim Derniere_ligne As Long
    Dim ligne_en_cours As Long
    Dim libelle As String

    Derniere_ligne = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For ligne_en_cours = 2 To Derniere_ligne

    libelle = Cells(ligne_en_cours, 4).Value


    If libelle = "XZ" Then
     Rows(ligne_en_cours).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 'this will change colour for whole row
End If


    Next


End Sub
```

I say

```
libelle = Cells(ligne_en_cours, 4).Value
```

But I would like to replace the 4 per the index of libelle who would return me 4 becuase sometimes, I can have 1 column more and then all would be false.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your original question and do not get out of the original scope as much, stackoverflow is meant to Q&A not like a traditional forum